# PromQL query to show the number of incoming requests accurately

Tags: .net-core, grafana, promql, prometheus-net

I'm having this problem with grafana to query the number of requests incoming to my service.
Using Prometheus-net on my dotnet core Service, I have the "http_requests_received_total" which is a counter metric.

I run a 100 requests to Postman, ideally what I'd like to see is that at 12:20, a 100 requests came in (which is visible from seeing the counter go from 0 requests to 100 requests).
However, when using rate() or increase(), or sum(rate/increase), I keep getting approximate results and it's never an exact 100 requests.

Can anyone point me into a direction on how I can achieve this or read up upon it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus may return fractional results from [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. If you need exact integer results from `increase()` function, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is a Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It returns the expected integer results from the `increase()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping for a different answer, but I just succumbed to accepting this one and graphed 2 panels, 
1 for the increase and 1 for the normal counter going up. and from the second one, we should be able to infer the exact number